# Calculating the values and appending them as a column in the dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I'm working on an airline dataset. I've to calculate the number of adults, children's and infants per airline_pnr number and then append those values as a column in a data frame.

Pax Type: Passenger type(Adult(ADT), Children(CHD), Infant(INF))

```
+-------------+----------+
| airline_pnr |Pax_Type  |
+-------------+----------+
| EIPBGB      | ADT      |
| EIPBGB      | ADT      |
| EIPBGB      | CHD      |
| EIPBGB      | INF      |
| UH7EQV      | ADT      |
| UH7EQV      | ADT      |
| YVEEW       | ADT      |
| YVEEW       | ADT      |
| DR6YWR      | ADT      |
| DR6YWR      | ADT      |
| DR6YWR      | ADT      |
| DR6YWR      | CHD      |
| DR6YWR      | INF      |
| QJ2ESP      | ADT      |
| QJ2ESP      | CHD      |
| JL6E9T      | ADT      |
| VGYD5V      | ADT      |
| YVEG1       | ADT      |
| YVEG1       | ADT      |
+-------------+----------+
```

Expected output:

```
+--------+----------+--------------+-----------------+---------------+
|air_pnr | Pax Type | no_of_adults | no_of_childrens | no_of_infants |
+--------+----------+--------------+-----------------+---------------+
| EIPBGB | ADT      |            2 |               1 |             1 |
| UH7EQV | ADT      |            2 |               0 |             0 |
| YVEEW  | ADT      |            2 |               0 |             0 |
| DR6YWR | ADT      |            3 |               1 |             1 |
| QJ2ESP | ADT      |            1 |               1 |             0 |
| JL6E9T | ADT      |            1 |               0 |             0 |
| VGYD5V | ADT      |            1 |               0 |             0 |
| YVEG1  | ADT      |            2 |               0 |             0 |
+--------+----------+--------------+-----------------+---------------+
```

My Efforts:

```
df= df.value_counts(['airline_pnr', 'Pax Type']) 

df = df.to_frame()

df= df.rename(columns = {0: "freq"})
```

But not getting the desired results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use groupby on the `'air_pnr'` variable, and them use the `size()`
which counts the number of occurrences of each value.

```
df.groupby(['air_pnr','Pax_Type']).size()
```

Comment: The community encourages adding explanations alongisde code, rather than purely code-based answers (see [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300837/what-comment-should-i-add-to-code-only-answers)).

Comment: Hey, your code gives an  AttributeError: 'DataFrameGroupBy' object has no attribute 'value_counts'